# Editing a lisp file in emacs with SBCL

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, sbcl

Ok so i am trying to get started with lisp and slime and i am running into some problems. I have correctly installed emacs and slime and SBCL but i run into problems when trying to edit files. I am doing this all on mac osx lion though i dont think that makes a difference. So this maybe stupid but when i first enter the terminal i enter

```
$ emacs <myfile.lisp>
```

and then it opens up my file but then slime is not running so i do..

```
M-x: slime
```

but when i do that  is now gone and all i see is the "REPL" (i think) anyway it just shows me

```
*
```

and then i can enter things like

```
*15
15
```

but now i can't get back to my file so that i can compile it. Could somone please hlep me through this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried C-x b (switch-to-buffer) or C-x C-b (list-buffers)?

Comment: Press `C-h t` and go through it – it's worth it, then make sure Slime is configured correctly (you might want to use `(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))` in your `.emacs`), and use `C-c C-k` in a lisp buffer to compile the file, or `C-c C-c` to compile toplevel forms. Also, most Emacs users (unlike, say, Vi users) leave Emacs running and open files with `C-x C-f` rather than opening a new session for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, that switches the current window's buffer to the previous or next buffer.

For a more interactive approach, split the screen vertically <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (or horizontally <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>), so you may see your code and try something out on the REPL. You may switch windows with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (remember, O as in Other). You may close a window (not the buffer) with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

However, you'd better search for an [Emacs tutorial](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbie), as all of this is very basic. I also recommend you start with a graphical Emacs, such as [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/). Some people prefer [other versions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS), which integrate better with Mac OS X but also have lots of different keybindings and come with extra packages. I personally prefer having similar installations and keybindings in whatever OS I'm using.